# Struts : call a a method of DispatchAction from another DispatchAction

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I want to call a a method of dispatchAction from another dispatch action.
I want that when I click on update or delete "Inside display user method" will be diplayed on my jsp.

**Struts config file**

```
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/index.jsp" parameter="methodtocall" name="UserForm" path="/UserAction" scope="session" type="com.tk20.UserAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/dispatch.do?getMethodtocall=display.do" />
    </action>

    <action path="/dispatch.do?getMethodtocall=display" parameter="getMethodtocall" name="UserForm" scope="session" type="com.tk20.TestDispatchAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
    </action>

    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp" />
</action-mappings>
```

**dispactch action classes**

```
public class UserAction extends DispatchAction {

    /* forward name="success" path="" */
    private final static String SUCCESS = "success";

    /**
     * This is the Struts action method called on
     * http://.../actionPath?method=myAction1,
     * where "method" is the value specified in <action> element : 
     * ( <action parameter="method" .../> )
     */
    public ActionForward add(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        UserForm userForm = (UserForm) form;

        return mapping.findForward("dispatch");
    }


    public ActionForward update(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        UserForm userForm = (UserForm) form;
        userForm.setMessage("Inside update user method.");
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

    public ActionForward delete(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        UserForm userForm = (UserForm) form;
        userForm.setMessage("Inside delete user method.");
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

```
public class TestDispatchAction extends DispatchAction {

    /* forward name="success" path="" */
    private final static String SUCCESS = "success";

    /**
     * This is the Struts action method called on
     * http://.../actionPath?method=myAction1,
     * where "method" is the value specified in <action> element : 
     * ( <action parameter="method" .../> )
     */
    public ActionForward display(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        UserForm userForm = (UserForm) form;
        userForm.setMessage("Inside display user method.");
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

}
```

JSP page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.forms[0].action = "UserAction.do?methodtocall=add";
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="UserAction">
    <table>
        <tr><td><bean:write name="UserForm" property="message" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><html:submit value="Add" onclick="submitForm()" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><html:submit property="methodtocall" value="update" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><html:submit property="methodtocall">delete</html:submit></td></tr>
    </table>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: I don't see your mappings of `UserAction` in your `struts-config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass method name to your parameter variable, which you want to call

```
<action path="/dispatch.do?getMethodtocall=display" parameter="getMethodtocall" name="UserForm" scope="session" type="com.tk20.TestDispatchAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
</action>

<action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp" />
```